# How to import pg-types using ES6 syntax?

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

Could you provide an example for node-pg-types with the "import" statement and not "require" so that type translators get registered for node-postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it can be done as ([from github](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types/issues/139#issuecomment-1231796570)):

```
import { builtins, getTypeParser } from 'pg-types'
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible, because it's not being [exported](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/packages/pg/lib/index.js). The best you can do is.

```js
import pg from 'pg'

const { types } = pg
```